# OneTime SetUp Registration Screen in APP?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

hi i want to implement in my application that user have to register one time and when he opens the app again he  should directly go to welcome activity without going to registration Activity. so how to implement this.

```
savedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(savedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_SHOW_ABOUT_ON_APP_START, true)){        
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    savedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(PREF_SHOW_ABOUT_ON_APP_START, false).commit(); // YOu could do this line within the SetupActivity to ensure they have actually done what you wanted
    finish();
} else {
    // Go somewere else
}
```

I tried this
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are the steps:

- in your setup/registration screen, after register button clicked and your job is done, save the result of action in shared preferences with a constant key.
- create a splash activity, make it your initial activity.
- in the splash activity's onResume method, check the related key for value.

  - if registered, fire the main activity
  - else display the settings/registration activity

Answer (score 0):

Create Two Activity XML Files. one is for Registration, Another is for App. but you should have only one Activity Class. in the class onCreate() function check the preference that the user is already resgistered or not. if registered, show the Main App XML file if not show Registration XML

**Edited:**

```
SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean status = preference.getBoolean("registration_completed", false);

if (status){
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_form);
}else{
    setContentView(R.layout.main_app);
}
```

Comment: i know this is very basic but when i write this code then he is telling declare method setDialogLayoutResource and i already extend activity so how can i do this please let me know thanks

Comment: There was a mistake, i'm sorry t should be `setContentView()` not setDialogLayoutResource() i've corrected my Answer

Comment: i did with setContentView but both the time he goes to else statement either its first time or next time please let me know how to resolve

Comment: it means there is no preference saved. here i posted the code just to read the preference. and i assumed you know everything about preferences. goto this link. here i posted one answer for a fella for edit & save / reading preference

Comment: hi kirk where is link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20607003/3082414 go there and check there is an accepted answer which is mine