# Show alert for 15 minute in android on button click

Tags: android, timer, handler

I want my alert to be appear for 15 minutes when user click button 5 times.Please help me I am not able to understand handler in android.

```
if(btn_count==5){
                          handler = new Handler();
                        Timer timer = new Timer();
                        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            alert("Your account has been blocked for 15 minutes due to 5 unsuccessfull attempts.");
                                            btn_count=0;
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // error, do something
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        };

                        timer.schedule(task, 0, 60*1000);
```

Comment: Just don't please

Comment: put alert code here

Comment: This method to temporarily disable login can be easily bypassed with an app restart, use shared preferences to keep track on login counts. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606738/temporarily-disable-login-after-failed-attempts

Comment: Hey i want something like this,if wrong password enter for 5 times than show same popup for 15 minute.Do not allow user to login.

Comment: you should store time as suggested by @RamithDR and Don't use `CountDownTimer` or `Timer` if user changes System time. timer will be skipped for that much time , use `Handler` instead

Answer (score 0):

**try to put this in alert dialog method**

Step 1 : change this

```
if(btn_count==5){
    alert("Your account has been blocked for 15 minutes due to 5 unsuccessfull attempts.");
}
```

Step 2 : Put this in alert code

```
 btn_count= 0;
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dismiss();
                }
            }, 900000);
```

Comment: Hey it works..and what if i want condition for more than 5 wrong login attempts for password than show same alert for 15 minute..

Comment: put some other variable and increases this on onclick of login button when wrong and if value == 5 than display dialog in same way

Comment: But i have to stop user from login if wrong attempts for more than 5 times

Comment: thought your self

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
//Show the Alert here
}, 90000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(btn_count==5){


    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loader);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();


    new CountDownTimer(900000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }

    }.start();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First don't use `Handler` inside `Timer` only use `Handler` which are better.

Have one variable that stores clicks

`private int clickCount = 0;`

and in `onClick()` of your button do like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    if(v == btn_login && clickCount < 5){
        if(WrongPassword){
            clickCount++;
            if(clickCount == 5){
                showAlert();
            }
        }else{
            clickCount = 0;
        // put your login code here
        }
    }

}

private long mLastClickTime = 0
private void showAlert(){
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    alert("Your account has been blocked for 15 minutes due to 5 unsuccessfull attempts.");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putLong("mLastClickTime", mLastClickTime);
    editor.commit();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dismiss();
                clickCount = 0;
            }
        }, 900000);
}
```

and finally in `onCreate()` you need to check that previously user have tried more than 5 times or not(in case user kills the app an come back immediately)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Long oldLastClick = prefs.getLong("mLastClickTime", 0);
    if (oldLastClick != 0) {
        Long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if((currentTime < oldLastClick) < 90000){
            clickCount = 5;
            alert("Your account has been blocked for 15 minutes due to 5 unsuccessfull attempts.");

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dismiss();
                    clickCount = 0;
                }
            }, (currentTime - oldLastClick));

            return; 


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Shivangi, I believe that CountDownTimer is best match to your requirement because you can update UI thread from there as well.

You can achieve this in following way:

Set a count so that you can have button click count.

```
if(btnClickCount == 5)
{
   //Show alert to user
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You account locked for next 15 min.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //Pretended that you have login button like this.
   //Disable login button so that user will not click this until it enabled again after so called 15 minute
   btnLogin.setEnabled(false);

   //Start count down timer from 15 minute like this
   CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(900000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            //You can update your UI here if you want,like time remaining for re-login attempt. So that user UX appear good. It'll be called every second as I set it to 1000.
           // You can user a dialog to show time remaining to unlock account and use this method to get formatted time
           String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))); 
           //Output will be like this 00:14:59
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            //Enable button as 15 minute lock period is over. and reset the button click counter
            btnClickCount = 0;
            btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.start();

}
```

You can break down this code into function as well.

Thanks